# How do I use Javascript in the Zapier Code Zap to convert incoming data into the JSON format Zapier requires?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, zapier

I solved the problem described below with the malformed JSON output. I created a Code Zap with the following JS:

```
let url = 'https://api.iterable.com/api/export/data.json?dataTypeName=emailOpen&range=Today&onlyFields=email&onlyFields=createdAt&onlyFields=templateId&onlyFields=messageId&onlyFields=campaigniD&onlyFields=contentID'
let iterableData = 'undefined'

let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
    'Api-Key': '----------redacted----------------',
    },
});

iterableData = await response.text()

iterableData = iterableData.replace(/\}/g, "},")
iterableData = "[" + iterableData.slice(0, -2) + "]"
let iterableJSON = JSON.parse(iterableData)

output = {iterableJSON}
```

---

I have an API that is outputting JSON content in a format Zapier does not like.

The data is output like this:

```
{"city":"Warren Township","country":"United States"}
{"city":"New York","country":"United States"}
{“city”:”Stamford”,”country”:”United States"}
```

When I use the retrieve poll with the Webhook Zap, the error message I get is: “We couldn't find an entry”.

According to Zapier documentation, Zapier is expecting it to start and end with brackets, and with commas, like this:

```
[{"city":"Warren Township","country":"United States"},
{"city":"New York","country":"United States"},
{“city”:”Stamford”,”country”:”United States"}]
```

I tried using a Code by Zapier Zap to pull in the data as text and convert it into JSON, but without success. This is what I tried but it produced this message:

```
Error while retrieving: You must return a single object or array of objects.
```

```
return fetch(https://api.iterable.com/api/export/data.json?dataTypeName=emailSend&range=Yesterday, {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: { 'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'User-Agent' : 'My-App',
  'Accept': '*/*', }, }) 

.then(response => response.text())
.catch(error => console.log('Error while fetching:', error))

callback(error, "output")

let xStr = response.text();
let obj = JSON.parse(xStr);

output = {obj};
```

Any help figuring this out is appreciated!

Comment: You say that the API outputs JSON, but that is not valid JSON. Did you *type* it and make typos, or is that really a copy of the output you get? If so, it is only normal that Zapier complains. It just isn't valid JSON. Fix it at the source so the output *is* valid JSON.

Comment: You tagged the question with JSON. Please read the description of the tag: _Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)._ That will show you your problem.

Comment: The output is how it is actually output - I know it is not valid. Unfortunately I don't control the source so I can't fix the output.  Only option is to modify the output from within Zapier or another tool